# unbounded field in crystal report by pass parameter at runtime

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I have a report in crystal report.
In that report, I need to set the field to 'Go' if the value is 0, and set the field to 'NoGo' if the value is 1.

I have created an unbound field string and write formula as below:

```
if {?idline}=1 and tonumber({bevarage;1.torque})=0 then {@UnboundString2}='Go' 
else if {?idline}=1 and tonumber({bevarage;1.torque})=1 then {@UnboundString2}='NoGo'
```

but this is not working and always returns an empty string from unbounded field.
Please help me to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Assignment operator in Crystal is **:=** rather than **=**

Why not simply create a formula that depends on the parameter?